# Splitting field of $x^4 + 1$ over $Q$

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^4+1$.. so we conclude that all roots of $x^4 + 1$ is primitive 8th root of unity. And the generator is $e^\frac{(2πi)}{8}$. Which is equal to $\cos(2\pi/8) + i \sin(2\pi/8)$  and equal to $\frac{1+ i }{\sqrt{2}}$

And all other roots is generating by it. So my my doubt is

< Then splitting field should be $\mathbb{Q}( \frac{1+ i }{\sqrt{2}}$
). . But it's not , we solve it further and conclude that 1 and i must be there and splitting field must be $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt2 , i )$ . But in my opinions splitting field can be $\mathbb{Q}( \frac{1+ i }{\sqrt{2}}$ )
too because it's also contains all roots and can even generate $ \sqrt{2}$ and $i$>

Can please anyone help me to solve this puzzle for me and why we choose   splitting field to $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt2 , $i$ )$ .

Comment: What is $F$ here?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter rational no

Comment: You conclusion is correct and $\mathbb{Q} ((1+i)/\sqrt{2})$ is the splitting field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2, i)$ by closure, it is true that $\mathbb{Q}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}) \subseteq  \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2,i)$ .

Now since $i = \big(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}) ^2$ , $i \in \mathbb{Q}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2} )$ then so does $1+i$ and by closure $\sqrt 2 \in\mathbb{Q}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2} ) $

By definition $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2, i)$ is the smallest subfield to contain $\sqrt 2$ and $i$, thus $\mathbb{Q}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2} ) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2, i)$

Comment: Ohhkey , i understand that $i$ and \sqrt2 is part of $\mathbb{Q}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}) . But I didn't understand that why a field gernating by two insider elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}) equal to it. And why it's smallest . I understand $\mathbb{Q}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}) should be smallest but why $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2, i)$ is ? Thank you  so much for helping me

Comment: Because gernally Q ( √2 ) is super field of Q.  So Q ( √2 , i ) should also bigger filed. Isn't ?

Comment: If $F$ is a field and $a,b$ are elements in some extension of $F$, then we denote $F(a,b)$ as smallest subfield which contains $a,b$ and $F$. That means any if you find that for some field $E$, $a,b \in E$ and $F \subseteq E$ then $F(a,b) \subseteq E$ and similar with the case of $F(a)$

Comment: so for making final splitting field ,;we need to always see generator and try to produce independent terms those together make the generator. Is it ?

Comment: @AmitMittal: it is not necessary to write the final answer in form $\mathbb{Q} (i, \sqrt{2})$ but this form may look visually simpler because it avoids fractions like $(1+i)/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh ohkey , now clear like a mirror. Thank you soo soo soo much !!